А как сделать, чтобы в конце каждой строки, которая начинается на <strong> поставить </strong>
А как сделать, чтобы в конце каждой строки, которая начинается на <strong> поставить </strong>

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Так text.replace(/(?<=^\s*<strong>.*)$/g, "$0</strong>");

Точно не так, как выше.
